# How to inline/bundle .json files in Angular NPM Package

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

I am trying to create an NPM Package from an Angular module that I want to reuse in multiple Angular apps. My Angular module uses `ng2-translate` that gets some localization strings from `.json` files. How do I bundle/inline these `.json` files in my package?

Comment: try to use file-loader and then require your .json file in one of you ts files

Comment: The problem is: in the compile step it does not copy the .json files to the lib folder (see that guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using an extra gulp copy task that copies everything in my src/locales dir to lib/locales, but I'm still open to better suggestions.